# What does -1 mean in this code([file for file in os.listdir(folder_dir) if file.find("xlsx") != -1])?

Tags: python, for-loop, find

How can you interpret the code?

```
[file for file in os.listdir(folder_dir) if file.find("xlsx") != -1]
```

Also, what does `-1` mean in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string `find` function gives `-1` automatically if it does not appear in the string. So your code is doing a condition (`if` statement) to check whether `xlsx` is in the string.

The `str.find` function is meant to find the index of the substring being in the string.

Here is an example:

```
>>> a = '123abc'
>>> a.find('a')
3
>>> a.find('Something that is not in the string')
-1
>>>
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find):

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring *sub* is found within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments *start* and *end* are interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if *sub* is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that the code snippet loops through files within `folder_dir` using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

For each such `file`, we check whether the filename contains the substring `xlsx`, using [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.find).

If the substring occurs in the string, it will return the first index within the string at which it occurs, otherwise, it will return `-1`.

From the Python documentation:

> Return the lowest index in the string where substring sub is found
> within the slice `s[start:end]`. Optional arguments start and end are
> interpreted as in slice notation. Return `-1` if sub is not found.

The condition `file.find("xlsx") != -1` will be `True` for any filename which contains `xlsx`, and hence the filename will be added to the list.

Hence, this code:

```
[file for file in os.listdir(folder_dir) if file.find("xlsx") != -1]
```

is simply making a list of all the files in `folder_dir` containing `xlsx`.

More generally, you'd probably want to check whether the filename *ends with* `.xlsx` instead, using [`str.endswith`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=find#str.endswith):

```
[file for file in os.listdir(folder_dir) if file.endswith(".xlsx")]
```